# Wicket, specify default contents of child element in basepage

Tags: html, wicket

I found a few examples on the use of wicket child and extend tags.
E.g. a basepage with a child element that is implemented by two different childpages.

Is it possible to use one parent and one child that overrides a specific part of the page where the parent page defines default content for that (child) part?

So instead of adding to the content, the child would replace that part?

If I put any content in between the child element on the basepage, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Wicket tags identified by wicket:id are not allowed in between <wicket:child> and </wicket:child> tags
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use composition instead of inheritance for such use cases.
I.e. use a Panel that is created by a (protected) factory method. The child page should override this method and create a different Panel.